# CSS transition в React

Tags: css, reactjs

Допустим я хочу сделать блок у которого `className='box'`
При клике на этот блок, его цвет фона меняется на красный, путём добавления класса `red`

В обычном `html/css/js` приложении я бы сделал так:

```
const block = document.querySelector('.box');

block.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.classList.toggle('red'))
```

И благодаря `.box { transition: background 0.3s }` в CSS цвет изменится плавно.

Но в React если `className` будет изменён, плавности не будет, тк компонент перерисуется, у него сразу будет `className='box red'`

Как правильно (по соглашениям/архитектуре) добавлять плавность в React приложениях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```js
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import './styles.css';

const App = () => {
  const [redState, setRedState] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        className={classNames('box', {
          red: redState
        })}
      />

      <button onClick={() => setRedState(!redState)}>Change state</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-in-out;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Или так же как в ответе выше, но без использования сторонней библиотеки:

```
const App = () => {
  const [redState, setRedState] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        className={`box ${redState ? 'red' : ''}`}
      />

      <button onClick={() => setRedState(!redState)}>Change state</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```